# How do I delete a certain line (given a line #) in a file through python?

Tags: python, text-files

I want to delete a line of text from a .txt file given an integer corresponding to the txt file's line number. For example, given the integer 2, delete line 2 of the text file.
I'm sort of lost on what to put into my program.

```
f = open('text1.txt','r+')
g = open('text2.txt',"w")

line_num = 0
search_phrase = "Test"
for line in f.readlines():
    line_num += 1
    
    if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
        print("text found a line" , line_num)
        decision = input("enter letter corresponding to a decision: (d = delete lines, s = save to new txt) \n")
        if decision == 'd':
             //delete the current line
        if decision == 's':
             //save the current line to a new file
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Since you are already iterating over the lines, and the plan involves explicitly writing every line that is to be "saved", all you need to do is *just not write* the lines that will be deleted. Nothing about the code shown makes the line number useful or relevant.

Comment: You don't need to increment the `line_num` variable yourself. Use `for line_num, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), 1):`

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
with open('text1.txt','r') as f, open('text2.txt',"w") as g:

    to_delete=[2,4]

    for line_number, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), 1):
            if line_number not in to_delete:
                g.write(line)
            else:
                print(f'line {line_number}, "{line.rstrip()}" deleted')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes.

```
f = open('data/test.txt','rb')
text = f.readlines() # all lines are read into a list and you can  acess it as a list

deleted_line = text.pop(1) #line is deleted and stored into the variable
print(text)
print(deleted_line)

f.write(text) # here you save it with the new data, you can always delete the data in the file to replace by the new one
```